# Connect Azure SQL Database to Provider Hosted Add-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, sql

If I have both a provider hosted add-in and an SQL database running on the same Azure server, how do I access the database from within my Sharepoint add-in?
Thank you!

Comment: check this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a30324/provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-in-with-sql-database-in-azure/

Comment: i added that link as answer for community benefit, it will great if you mark it answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Please follow [this blog for the more information.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a30324/provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-in-with-sql-database-in-azure/)

- Microsoft Azure Account: If you do not have Azure account, open a
  free Azure account. It comes with [one-month free trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/free-trial/).
- Office 365 subscription
- Visual Studio 2013/2015: You need to have Visual Studio installed on
  your machine.
- Install the [Azure SDK for Visual Studio 2015](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=518003) or the [Azure SDK for
  Visual Studio 2013](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=324322).